# PHP Deprecated: Non-static method should not be called statically in

Tags: php

Alguém pode ajudar?

Estou recebendo esse erro ao executar uma rotina.

> Deprecated: Non-static method TTranslation::Translate() should not be called statically in C:\wamp64\www\Livro\app.widgets\TTranslation.class.php on line 105

**transp.php**

```
<?php    
/*
 * Inclui a classe TTranslation
 */
include_once 'app.widgets/TTranslation.class.php';

/*
 * Define a linguagem como português
 */
TTranslation::setLanguage('pt');
echo "Em Português:<br>\n";

/*
 * Imprime palavras traduzidas
 */
echo _t('Function') . "<br>\n";
echo _t('Table') . "<br>\n";
echo _t('Tool') . "<br>\n";

/*
 * Define a linguagem como italiano
 */
TTranslation::setLanguage('it');
echo "Em Italiano:<br>\n";
// imprime palavras traduzidas
echo _t('Function') . "<br>\n";
echo _t('Table') . "<br>\n";
echo _t('Tool') . "<br>\n";
?>
```

**TTranslation.class.php**

```
<?php
/**       
 * classe TTranslation
 * classe utilitária para tradução de textos
 */
class TTranslation
{
    private static $instance;   // instância de TTranslation
    private $lang;              // linguagem destino

    /**
     * método __construct()
     * instancia um objeto TTranslation
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->messages['en'][] = 'Function';
        $this->messages['en'][] = 'Table';
        $this->messages['en'][] = 'Tool';
        $this->messages['pt'][] = 'Função';
        $this->messages['pt'][] = 'Tabela';
        $this->messages['pt'][] = 'Ferramenta';
        $this->messages['it'][] = 'Funzione';
        $this->messages['it'][] = 'Tabelle';
        $this->messages['it'][] = 'Strumento';
    }

    /**
     * método getInstance()
     * retorna a única instância de TTranslation
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        // se não existe instância ainda
        if (empty(self::$instance))
        {
            // instancia um objeto
            self::$instance = new TTranslation;
        }
        // retorna a instância
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * método setLanguage()
     * define a linguagem a ser utilizada
     * @param $lang = linguagem (en,pt,it)
     */
    public static function setLanguage($lang)
    {
        $instance = self::getInstance();
        $instance->lang = $lang;
    }

    /**
     * método getLanguage()
     * retorna a linguagem atual
     */
    public static function getLanguage()
    {
        $instance = self::getInstance();
        return $instance->lang;
    }

    /**
     * método Translate()
     * traduz uma palavra para a linguagem definida
     * @param $word = Palavra a ser traduzida
     */
    public function Translate($word)
    {
        // obtém a instância atual
        $instance = self::getInstance();
        // busca o índice numérico da palavra dentro do vetor
        $key = array_search($word, $instance->messages['en']);
        // obtém a linguagem para tradução
        $language = self::getLanguage();
        // retorna a palavra traduzida
        // vetor indexado pela linguagem e pela chave
        return $instance->messages[$language][$key];
    }
} // fim da classe TTranslation

/**
 * método _t()
 * fachada para o método Translate da classe Translation
 * @param $word = Palavra a ser traduzida
 */
function _t($word)
{
    return TTranslation::Translate($word);
}
?>
```

Comment: Isso não é um erro, é um aviso (`warning`). A função `Translate` não é estática, então por que você não simplesmente usa o `$this`? Ou então por que não a transforma em estática? Essa segunda alternativa é horrível, mas a classe já está mal modelada mesmo...

Comment: Se tem um `getInstance` estático, seguindo o padrão *Singleton*, os outros métodos deviam ser de instancia. Mas pela forma como está a tentar utilizar também suspeito que não seja isso que quer.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Jefferson Quesado, como seria a forma correta então ?

Answer (score 2):

O problema é uma aviso de que a função não é `static`:

```
function _t($word)
{
    return TTranslation::Translate($word);
}
```

Dessa forma que vc chamou a função `Translate()` ela representa uma função estática, existem duas opções para resolver esse aviso:

A primeira é chamar a função como sendo não estárica:

```
function _t($word)
{
    return TTranslation->Translate($word);
}
```

A segunda é transformar a função `Translate()` em `static`:

```
static function Translate($word)
{
    // obtém a instância atual
    $instance = self::getInstance();
    // busca o índice numérico da palavra dentro do vetor
    $key = array_search($word, $instance->messages['en']);
    // obtém a linguagem para tradução
    $language = self::getLanguage();
    // retorna a palavra traduzida
    // vetor indexado pela linguagem e pela chave
    return $instance->messages[$language][$key];
}
```